# How to input file from commmad line and remove duplicates UNIX

Tags: bash, unix, scripting

I have one file called garbage.txt and I have written the program, but I am not sure if this is the correct way. the program asks to handle invalid inputs such as missing parameters empty file(use file -i and check application/x-empty) and text file(use file -i and check text/plain). This is what i have so far.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line 
do 
  echo $line
done < garbage.txt 
sort garbage.txt | uniq -u
```

Comment: Why not use `sort -u garbage.txt > garbage.txt.unique`?  Why do you need the `read` loop?

Comment: How are parameters passed to your program? On the command line? If this is an assignment, it may be best to paste the entire text of the question into your question. Look at documentation for the `if` command in the shell and the `file` and `grep` commands.

Comment: This is the question        
Write a shell script that will take an input file from command line and remove identical lines (or duplicate lines from the file). Make sure, script handle invalid inputs such as
- Missing parameter
- Empty file ( use file –i and check application/x-empty )
- Text file (  use file –i and check text/plain )

Comment: try something with `if [ $# -gt 0 ]`and `echo "Testing parameter $1" `

Comment: echo 'folder name' read folder     sort -u sample.txt | uniq -u